# Нужно поставить видеофон на всю высоту экрана

Tags: html, видео

Есть видео ширина кадра 1640, высота 924. Мне нужно что бы видео растягивалась по всей высоте экрана. Но при этом она сужается по ширине. Как я понял тег video не позволяет портить пропорции видео. Есть ли какое то решение, или проблема в самом видео

Comment: я смотрю, видео встает на всю высоту и ширину экрана. Мешает только навигационное меню.

Comment: Но мне нужно что бы было видно и навигационное меню и полностью видео. Что можно сделать добрые люди)

Comment: привидите пример того что вы делаете, и что в итоге должно получиться. Так не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0):

Проблему прямо решить не удалось. Видео на весь экран показывается, но мешает шапка. Для тех у кого может быть такая проблема. Я сделал так: при загрузке страницы скрыл меню, и он появляется при скролле вниз

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
   $(".main-nav").slideDown();
   return false;
   }
  else {
   $(".main-nav").slideUp();
   }
  });
```